# Can Tampermonkey edit popups from other extensions

Tags: chromium, tampermonkey

Is it possible to change other extension popups (like Google tag assistant legacy or even LastPass)?
Can't find documentation or anything about it, but it would be a lifesaver for my everyday automatization.

Answer (score 0):

Neither userscripts nor extensions have access to modify other extensions as it would be a security risk.